# How do you set the SoftwareComponent when publishing a Kotlin Multiplatform Library with the maven publish plugin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform, maven-publish

I'm struggling to understand how the Maven publish plugin gets the right `SoftwareComponent` to publish when publishing a kotlin multiplatform project.

In a simple java project, configuring the plugin is as follows:

```kotlin
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            groupId = "org.gradle.sample"
            artifactId = "library"
            version = "1.1"

            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
}
```

The `SoftwareComponent` is selected with the `from(components["java"])` declaration.

The tutorial for publishing a [kotlin multiplatform library](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-publish-lib.html#publish-an-android-library) skips this. Worse yet, when I leave it blank and publish to maven local, I get an empty pom.xml with no jar.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        register("lib", MavenPublication::class) {
         ...
        }
    }
    repositories {
         ...
    }
}
```

Even more confounding is if I change the above to this, I do get a sources jar, but I don't get publications for all the target platforms:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        withType<MavenPublication> {
         ...
        }
    }
    repositories {
         ...
    }
}
```

The only difference in the above is using `withType<MavenPublication>` versus `register("lib", MavenPublication::class)`. I'm not sure why using either of them yields completely different results.

How does one properly set the SoftwareComponent when publishing a Kotlin Multiplatform Library with the maven publish plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I turns out to properly configure the `maven-publish` plugin for publishing, care must be taken not to overwrite any properties in the maven publication block. That is

```
publishing {
    publications {
        withType<MavenPublication> {
            // Don't do this. Set the group and version on the project/subproject level.
            // The multiplatform plugin will read it appropriately.
            groupId = "org.gradle.sample"
            artifactId = "library"
            version = "1.1"
        }
    }
}
```

Following the comment above fixed things for me.